# How to do a double iterate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a class schedule. In `@appointments_monday`, we have different `appointment` that belongs to a specific `category`:

[image]

Certainly, `@appointment.each` would not work. It will produce something like:

[image]

because some appointment of a certain category could be empty. We're trying to loop through `@categories` to judge each `appointment`, but it turns out like this:

[image]

```
    <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
        <% @categories.each do |category| %>
            <% if appointment.category == category %>
              <%= appointment %>  
            <% else %>
                placeholder
            <% end %>    
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I think the problem is that `@categories.each` is looped over every time. How should we deal with this?

Comment: Can you show us the desired output? Is it the first diagram?

Comment: @Daiku yes, the first.

Comment: Then I think you just need to switch your inner and outer iterators.  But Carol's answer is probably more efficient, as the test to see if the category matches is in C, not ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about, instead of looping over both appointments and categories, you iterate over just categories once (since you want to output something for each category, whether it has an appointment or not) and check for the existence of any appointments with that category:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% category_appointments = @appointments.select {|a| a.category == category } %>
  <% if category_appointments.empty? %>
    <%= placeholder %>
  <% else %>
    <%= category_appointments %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`select` is a method on [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-docs.com/docs/ruby_1.9.3/classes/Enumerable.html) which is included in `Array`.

Comment: It works, really. But I still find this method quite counter intuitive. Is it possible to do with the `@appointments`? I feeled that is how a table should be filled.

Comment: Oh, I wonder if I'm misunderstanding the problem. You're filling in the cells of the table, and the row is for the set of all `appointment` objects in `@appointments`, and the columns are for each `category`, correct? I was thinking of it more like "Let's visit each cell in the row and see if anything belongs here" rather than "Let's place all the appointments in the cells where they belong". Does that help? I'm not really sure why you would want to iterate over @appointments, could you elaborate if it sounds like I'm misunderstanding?